# Error protocol in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, polymorphism

I'm trying to implement my own Error type by reading the Apple's [document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/error) in Swift 3.

I have defined my error type like this:

```
enum MyError: Error {

  case unknown
  case offline
  case accountMissing

  var localizedDescription: String {

    switch self {
    case .unknown: return "Unknown Error"
    case .offline: return "Offline Error"
    case .accountMissing: return "Account Missing Error"
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have implemented a presenting function to display an error. (The arg error can be MyError or Error that are returned by system function.

```
func printError(_ error: Error) {
  print(error.localizedDescription) 
  // The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyError error 1.)
}
```

When MyError is passed to this function, for example printError(MyError.offline), I expected "Offline Error" as the result, but the results is

> The operation couldn’t be completed. (MyError error 1.)

, not "Offline Error" as I expected. To get the expected results, I need to force cast like this:

```
print((error as! MyError).localizedDescription)
```

I don't understand why this happens. MyError type inherited Error protocol.  Shouldn't the "error" act as MyError type without force casting?

(MyError is defined as enum here, but I also tried to define as a class.  The results was the same.)

Is there a comprehensive way to display arbitrary Error types to users?

---

I'm confused with Error protocol. I expected `func printError(_ error: Error)` should have accepted anything that is conformed to Error protocol, and would print localizedDescription of MyError type's own implementation.

I still don't understand why these two results are different. I assume it is because MyError is not a class but it's still not clear for me.  Could anyone give me clear explanation?

```
func printErrorA(_ error: Error) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func printErrorB(_ error: MyError) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

printErrorA(MyError.offline) // <--
printErrorB(MyError.offline) // <--
```

---

Thank you @martinr

**"Protocol extension members aren't class members so they can't be overridden by subclasses"**

**"protocol extension is statically dispatched"**

[Override of protocol default implementation in a subsubclass doesn't participate in dynamic dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007960/override-of-protocol-default-implementation-in-a-subsubclass-doesnt-participate/39008193#39008193)

https://nomothetis.svbtle.com/the-ghost-of-swift-bugs-future

After reading [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localised-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift)
I re-wrote my code like this

```
enum MyError : LocalizedError {
  case unknown
  case offline
  case accountMissing
  var errorDescription: String? {
    switch self {
    case .unknown: return "Unknown Error"
    case .offline: return "Offline Error"
    case .accountMissing: return "Account Missing Error"
    }
  }
}

func printErrorA(_ error: Error) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func printErrorB(_ error: MyError) {
  print(error.localizedDescription)
}

printErrorA(MyError.offline) // <-- Offline Error
printErrorB(MyError.offline) // <-- Offline Error
```

Comment: You mean you want a function that can print both your error enum and the system NSError?

Comment: try this : `func printError(_ error: MyError)`

Comment: printError(_ error: MyError)  does not accept Error type.

Comment: Yes, I need a way to accept both my custom error type and the system Error type.  Also I want to know the reason why 'error' does not act as MyError unless force down casting.  Seems contradicting polymorphism for me.

Comment: @user5865651: The linked-to Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localised-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift should answer your question *how* to make it work. – As for why your method does not work, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007960/override-of-protocol-default-implementation-in-a-subsubclass-doesnt-participate/39008193#39008193 and the related questions. If a method is only defined as default implementation in a protocol extension then it is statically dispatched.

Comment: (...cont.) Therefore `error.localizedDescription` calls the default implementation, and not that of your `MyError` type.