# Extend Error protocol

Tags: ios, swift

I've created a small example. I want that `localizedString()` invokes in `SomeError` enum. But I see that this method all time invokes in extension.
Wham am I doing wrong. Hope someone can solve my problem.

```
extension Error {
    func localizedString() -> String {
        return "extension"
    }
}

enum SomeError: Error {
    case test
    func localizedString() -> String {
        return "SomeError"
    }
}

func print(error: Error) {
    error.localizedString()
}

print(error: SomeError.test)
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? – [How to provide a localised description with an Error type in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localised-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift)

Comment: Your approach does not work because the method is *statically* dispatched. See this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509399/error-protocol-in-swift?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment66337865_39509399 to a similar question, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007960/override-of-protocol-default-implementation-in-a-subsubclass-doesnt-participate/39008193#39008193 for more details.