# Dynamic/runtime dispatch in Swift, or "the strange way structs behave in one man's opinion"

Tags: swift, dynamic, struct, error-handling, nslocalizedstring

I'm not horribly new to Swift, nor to Objective-C, but I saw some odd behavior when working with an `Error` subtype today that led me to dig a little deeper.

When working with an `NSString` subclass (yes, the below example functions similarly for classes **not** based on `NSObject`):

```
import Foundation

// Class version
class OddString : NSString {
    override var description: String {
        return "No way, José"
    }
}

let odd = OddString()

func printIt(_ string: NSString) {
    print(string.description)
}

print(odd.description)
printIt(odd)
```

I see what I expect to see:

```
No way, José
No way, José
```

However, when I write (*what I think is*) the equivalent code using a struct (`Error`) instead:

```
import Foundation

// Struct version
struct TestError : Error {
    var localizedDescription: String {
        return "I am a TestError"
    }
}

let explosive = TestError()

func printIt(_ error : Error) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

print(explosive.localizedDescription)
printIt(explosive)
```

I see:

```
I am a TestError
The operation couldn’t be completed. (SanityChecks.TestError error 1.)
```

This is really confusing to me. Is it deciding at *compile time* what method will be invoked on the struct passed in to `printIt`, regardless of what type it *actually* is?

Further: Is this difference in runtime behavior between classes and structs documented in the Swift Programming Guide, and can someone reference the section? I haven't found anything on this yet.

Comment: Compare [How to provide a localized description with an Error type in Swift?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift).

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39007960/override-of-protocol-default-implementation-in-a-subsubclass-doesnt-participate, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31431753/swift-protocol-extensions-overriding

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first example you're *overriding* the `description` property. This implementation is therefore added to `OddString`'s vtable (as it's a *class*), and can be dynamically dispatched to just fine, regardless of what the instance is statically typed as.

In your second example, you don't have a class – so no vtables. However you *are* conforming to a protocol. Protocols allow for dynamic dispatch via protocol witness tables (see [this great WWDC talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9By9KLs51Dc) on them), however this only happens for implementations of protocol *requirements*.

`localizedDescription` isn't a protocol requirement of the `Error` protocol, it's merely defined in a protocol extension of `Error` when you `import Foundation` (this is documented in [SE-0112](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0112-nserror-bridging.md)). Therefore it cannot be dynamically dispatched. Instead, it will be statically dispatched – so the implementation called is dependant on the *static type* of the instance.

That's the behaviour you're seeing here – when your `explosive` instance is typed as `TestError`, your implementation of `localizedDescription` is called. When typed as `Error`, the implementation in the `Error` extension is called (which just does a bridge to `NSError` and gets its `localizedDescription`).

If you want to provide a localised description, then you should conform your error type to [`LocalizedError`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/localizederror) instead, which defines `errorDescription` as a protocol requirement – thus allowing for dynamically dispatch. See [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176196/how-to-provide-a-localized-description-with-an-error-type-in-swift) for an example of how to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

`localizedDescription` is both an extension on the `Error` protocol and a property on your error type. When the compiler knows that your type implements the property, it uses it. When it doesn't, it uses the extension. There is no dynamic dispatch.

Contrast with your String example, where, by overriding the `description` member, the compiler puts a reference to your implementation in the vtable, and as such it will be dynamically dispatched.